# How to get decoded video frames using WinRT in .NET5

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, .net-5

I'm attempting to read decoded video frames in a .NET5 console app using the new WinRT Projection APIs.

I've spent many hours trying to piece it together using the following without success:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/use-opencv-with-mediaframereader
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-video-effects
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader
- https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2020/09/03/calling-windows-apis-in-net5/

This does open and start to decode frames, but I am unable to get access to them in the FrameAvailable event.

```
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer
            {
                Source = mediaSource,
                IsVideoFrameServerEnabled = true,
                IsMuted = true,
                IsLoopingEnabled = false,
                AudioDevice = default,

            };
            player.VideoFrameAvailable += FrameAvailable;
```

```
        private void FrameAvailable(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
        {
            var frame = VideoFrame.CreateWithSoftwareBitmap(bitmap);
            sender.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(frame.Direct3DSurface);//this Direct3DSurface is null

            using (var buffer = bitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.Write))
            {
                BitmapPlaneDescription bufferLayout = buffer.GetPlaneDescription(0);
                using (var reference = buffer.CreateReference())
                {
                    IntPtr start;
                    uint capacity;//bytes
                    ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out start, out capacity);
                    //process the pixels here
        ...
```

How can I get access to the decoded frames so that I can process the pixels?

Comment: You could refer to [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#use-mediaplayer-in-frame-server-mode) in the official document , which mentions that you need to use CopyFrameToStereoscopicVideoSurfaces to copy the contents of the frame to an IDirect3DSurface. Then you should get an object that implements IDirect3DSurface. So you could create a SoftwareBitmap and then uses that object to create a Win2D CanvasBitmap. The CanvasBitmap object implements IDirect3DSurface.

Comment: But in your scenario, you don’t create a CanvasBitmap, you just have created a softwareBitmap object, which doesn’t implement the IDirect3DSurface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm having trouble finding or new()ing anything that is the first argument of: CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(<I cannot find or new() anything that goes here due to errors>, <my SoftwareBitmap>). I've raised a related-but-separate issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D/issues/822